# Final Fantasy XIII Post-Completion Length

Tags: final-fantasy-13

How long, in approximate hours, does it take to get everything in Final Fantasy XIII that happens after you defeat the final boss?

This includes all the Cie'th Stones, Crystalarium mastery and any other side quests which can be left until the very end of the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on your style of playing. If you try to master everything, I would say about 80-100 hours of total play time, though I'm pretty sure someone has already done it in 20 or 25 :-)

Comment: Ive read in multiple places that when focussing on platinum trophy it will take about 90 hours using the standard path taken (growth egg, farming adamantoise etc) - So 80-100 is a pretty solid range imo.